# Running GTM Event Tracking in an iFrame on a 3rd party domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm inserting an iFrame into a 3rd party website as part of a browser extension and want to track the interaction of what the user clicks on, along with getting stats of its usage using GA and GTM event tracking. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I guess I need to do something when I'm inserting the iFrame within the extension to add the GTM / GA code? Is it even possible to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

well,pls make sure that the site has GTM installed and is running properly, then set your tag in GTM with the trigger for click-all elements.